# How to get Complete HTML Tags and Placed into textarea using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, doctype

I'm working to get a html source code value and place that into the particular textarea or div while clicking button. But i won't get entire HTML tags it results beginning tag is Meta tag and it will remove proper HTML tags. I need to get entire html source from `<!DOCTYPE html`

Here's my Demo

```js
$('#save_editor').click(function(){
var full_value=$("#editor").html();
$('#write_html').val(full_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor"> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>title</title> <style type="text/css"> // My style code </style> </head> </head> <body> <div>   <p>my body</p> </div> </body> </html> </div> <textarea id="write_html"></textarea> <button id="save_editor">save</button>
```

Here my Working Div with sample Image:
[image: SAMPLE IMAGE]
I need to change that div color and change text section in that div. How do I get the entire customize div with the HTML code.
 My DEMO [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/thirupathi/j64r54rj/4/). How to get a real source code function using Javascript and place into particular textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any html tag after the first one will be removed. To fix this just place your template code inside of a hidden textarea, then the value will be preserved literally.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j64r54rj/5/

```js
$('#save_editor').click(function(){
var full_value=$("#editor textarea").val();
$('#write_html').val(full_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor"><textarea style="display: none;"><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>title</title> <style type="text/css"> // My style code </style> </head> </head> <body> <div>   <p>my body</p> </div> </body> </html> </textarea> </div> <textarea id="write_html"></textarea> <button id="save_editor">save</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Uldall..Your answer is good..But i need to change that Html value for example : i need to change that inner text and inner image.When i put it in textarea it willnt working fine for me..any other idea for this..?

Comment: You should keep your code in the hidden text area and make modifications to it there then have .preview div that you can push the code into for the live preview. http://jsfiddle.net/j64r54rj/9/

Comment: Yes @Eric you'r right flow but when i get from that #editor div it will results without getting html tags.How to place without getting html tags into hidden textarea..?Any idea for this?

Comment: I think you're missing the idea. You store a working copy of your html in the hidden textarea, that way it is plain text and will preserve the doctype tag. Then you render the html in a preview div so the user can see what they're editing. When the user makes an edit you update the code in the  hidden textarea first, then render it in the preview area. When a user clicks save, you just give them the code stored in the hidden textarea, NOT the code in the div.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if JQuery `html()` will return what you want. But with plain javascript and a little tweaking you could get the result that you expect.

Using `document.documentElement.outerHTML` will get you the all the source code except the doctype. You can then grab the doctype using `document.doctype` and slap them together and you've got the complete source code.